# Adding an administrator user to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, users

How do you add an administrator user to SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 29):

If you're doing it via T-SQL:

Granting a Windows Login the ability to connect to SQL Server:

```
CREATE LOGIN [Domain\User] FROM WINDOWS;
```

or

```
CREATE LOGIN [Domain\Group] FROM WINDOWS;
```

If SQL Server-based login:

```
CREATE LOGIN [LoginName] WITH PASSWORD = 'SomePassword';
```

After that, you can do one of two things. You can add it to the membership of the sysadmin fixed server role using sp_addsrvrolemember:

```
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'LoginName', 'sysadmin';
```

or you can grant the login CONTROL SERVER permissions:

```
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [LoginName];
```

Answer (score 12):

Before that I think we need to be able to login to SQL Server first. I have experienced being a server administrator, but I couldn't login since SQL Server was installed by a Domain Admin account.

So you might need to start SQL Server with command-line option `-m` (single user mode),

```
sqlservr.exe -m
```

and then do as [K. Brian Kelley said](https://serverfault.com/questions/338/adding-an-administrator-user-to-sql-server-2008/421#421), or connect via management studio, as suggested by Jeff (the login will succeed)

More step-by-step instructions can be found in [SQL Server 2008: Forgot to add an administrator account?](http://blogs.ameriteach.com/chris-randall/2009/12/11/sql-server-2008-forgot-to-add-an-administrator-account.html?printerFriendly=true)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've installed SQL Server 2008 before, for whatever reason I was unable to login with SSMS.  Following your suggestion was exactly what I needed to do to fix the sysadmin account login.

Answer (score 10):

For completeness, the GUI method

From SQL Server Management Studio, under the **Security / Logins** folder for the database, right click Logins and select New Login:

[image]

Be sure to use the full `domain\username` format in the Login Name field, and check the **Server Roles** list to make sure the user gets the roles you want.

Answer (score 5):

Since there was no complete answer for me for solving this Problem, here is what i did, for SQLServer 2014

- Stop the SQL Server instance (Service Tab)
- Start the SQL Server instance (Service Tab, use the start parameter
  `-m`)
- Open a command sql shell (as admin): `sqlcmd -S <instance name> -E`

Type the following in the shell

```
CREATE LOGIN [<DOMAIN>\<user>] FROM WINDOWS
go
exec sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame='<DOMAIN>\<user>', @rolename='sysadmin'
go
```

- Stop the SQL Server instance (Service Tab)
- Start the SQL Server instance (Service Tab, remove the start parameter
  `-m`)

Comment: For me the key hint of this was the `go` commands; I'm used to SSMS so didn't think to use `go` to submit batch from command line client.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, there are two different things this could mean.

1. How do I create a new user account that has administrative rights?
2. I already have a windows user that is an administrator, how do I add that user to SQL?

Answers:

1. In SQL Management Studio, create a new login and add it to the sysadmin server role.
2. In SQL Management Studio, create a login connected to the Windows account or a group that it's a member of.  You might well find BUILTIN\Administrators is already there.